# The script for Adobe InDesign works in a strange way

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I've been trying to write a script for Adobe InDesign that moves frames with pictures. It works, but not as I expected. I can't figure out why the script moves frames located below 553 pixels on the y-axis every time I run it.

```
#target indesign


var currentDocument = app.activeDocument;

var targetImagePath = "path\\to\\picture";

var newWidth = 22.408;
var newHeight = 26;

var positionX1 = 274;
var positionX2 = 1655.408;

var positionY = 950; 

var allGraphics = currentDocument.allGraphics;

for (var i = 0; i < allGraphics.length; i++) {
  var graphic = allGraphics[i];

  if (graphic.itemLink && graphic.itemLink.filePath === targetImagePath) {
        var selectedFrame = graphic.parent;

        var frameBounds = selectedFrame.geometricBounds;

        selectedFrame.geometricBounds = [
          frameBounds[0],
          frameBounds[1],
          frameBounds[0] + newHeight,
          frameBounds[1] + newWidth
        ];

        graphic.fit(FitOptions.PROPORTIONALLY);
        
      if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[0] > 553) {
            selectedFrame.move([frameBounds[1], positionY]);
          }
        
        if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] <= 320 ) {
            
            selectedFrame.move([positionX1, frameBounds[0]]);
      } else if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] > 1496) {
            selectedFrame.move([positionX2, frameBounds[0]]);
          }
      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guess. Probably you need to change this:

```
if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[0] > 553) {
    selectedFrame.move([frameBounds[1], positionY]);
}
   
if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] <= 320 ) {
    selectedFrame.move([positionX1, frameBounds[0]]);
} else if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] > 1496) {
    selectedFrame.move([positionX2, frameBounds[0]]);
}
```

with this:

```
if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[0] > 553) {
    selectedFrame.move([frameBounds[1], positionY]);
  
    if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] <= 320 ) {
        selectedFrame.move([positionX1, frameBounds[0]]);
    } else if (graphic.parent.geometricBounds[1] > 1496) {
        selectedFrame.move([positionX2, frameBounds[0]]);
    }
}
```

It will skip all the frames with the top edge above 533.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I read my question and realized that I explained my problem in the wrong way. The real problem is that the script should move frames located on the left side at positionX1, frames located on the right side at positionX2, and frames located below 553 on the Y-axis should be moved to positionY. However, instead of moving the frames on the Y-axis to the desired position, the script moves them upward, away from the intended point at positionY. Additionally, the more times you run the script, the higher the frames move.

Comment: Please, make a scheme what you have and what you trying to get. Something like this (this is what I'm getting from the code, except resizing the frames): https://imgur.com/V2FZAyu Since your description doesn't seem match the code. It doesn't move items upward and it doesn't move them at all if I run the code second time.

Comment: Just in case, here is my test INDD file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IS48o-L7tnXhzrmdHAHUstTxN3LiLqxy/view?usp=share_link